# How to add a background to the final page of the document?

Tags: graphics, backgrounds

I want to add a background to the final page of the document. I have two images, one that I have added on the first page of the document works perfectly, but I am not sure how to add the second one.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[pages=some]{background}


\backgroundsetup{   %for first-page image
scale=1,
color=black,
opacity=0.5,
angle=0,
contents={%
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}
  }%
}  

 \title{TITLE}
 \author{AUTHOR}
 \date{DATE}
 \begin{document}
 \BgThispage  % first-page image

 \maketitle 

 \tableofcontents
 \include{chapter}

  %Here I want to add second-page image.

 \end{document}
```

Comment: You can use TikZ [remember picture, ovverlay] at the begining of specific pages.  You can use the afterpage package on the previous page.  You can use the lastpage package and `\AddToHook{shiput/background}{...}` to check for the last page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `tikz` package that allows you to write the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

### Explanation

Inside the environment `tikzpicture` is defined a `node` at  the centre of the current page. This node will display anything between its `{...}`. It just happens that I told it to `\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}`.

Now for this to work correctly, you need to tell `tikz` that this `tikzpicture` is an `overlay` and that It will be superposed to whatever is below it on the paper.

The `remember picture` is used to tell tikz that this `tikzpicture` goes into an `.aux` file and will be compiled with other elements. For simplicity, let's say that this allows the tikzpicture to know where the centre of the page is.  Try removing this option and you will have the tikzpicture move to the top of the page.

refs:

- https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.13.1
- https://tikz.dev/tikz-shapes#sec-17.13.2

Comment: There woulld be a problem putting this on the top of the same page as \chapter due to \clearpage (or \cleardoublepage).

Answer (score 3):

To demonstrate my comment about lastpage:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{refcount}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=1\relax
     \put (0pt,-\paperheight) {\transparent{0.5}\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}
  \fi
  \ifnum\value{page}=\getpagerefnumber{LastPage}\relax
     \put (0pt,-\paperheight) {\transparent{0.5}\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-b}}
  \fi
}

 \title{TITLE}
 \author{AUTHOR}
 \date{DATE}

 \begin{document}
 
 \maketitle 

 \tableofcontents

\chapter{First}

  \pageref{LastPage}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: This works very well, thanks. But can the last page be completely devoid of headers and page numbers? I used `\thispagestyle{empty}` just before `\pageref{LastPage}` but it only removed the header and not the page number.

Comment: It worked for me.  \chapter uses \thispagestyle{plain}, but that shouldn\t stop another \thispagestyle.

Comment: LaTeX also provides `\thetotalpages` and `\PreviousTotalPages` which would make it independent of the `page` counter (which can be `1` more than once) and a manual `\pageref` at the last page. → `\ifnum\thetotalpages=1` and `\ifnum\thetotalpages=\PreviousTotalPages`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel - I take it this is a new feature?

Comment: @JohnKormylo I just stumbled across it in `source2e` when answering another question with `shipout/background` since it is in the same section.